# Ubuntu headset with single p3 input - When mic is on headphone is off

Tags: audio, ubuntu-14.04, headphone-jack

I have a single P3 input on my notebook and i bought a headset to use both the headphone and the mic.

When i go to sound settings and set the sound input to be the headset mic the headset phone does not work and vice-versa.

Doing hdajackretask initially shows the following

[image: Internal mic ,internal speaker and headphone]

On the "Black headphone,left side pin" i have the options :

- Headphone
- Line out (Front)
- Line out (Center/LFE)
- Line out (Back)
- Line out (Side)
- Internal speaker
- Internal speaker LFE
- Internal speaker (Back)
- Internal mic
- Not connected.

Upon showing unconnected pins

I have a two not connected pins that shows Microphone (not intermal mic).
This is the override i'm trying to apply:

[image: Audiorejack with unconnected pins]

Overriding it gives me :

```
 tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig: Device or resource busy
```

So i followed [this thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/):

In which tells me to kill whatever is using the audio in my case pulseaudio.

After killing pulseaudio and applying i then get

```
 tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig: No such device
```

And this is where i'm stuck right now.

Comment: Same issues as you. I'm using Samsung NP900X3D laptop.